# GSL - Multivariate regression

Tags: c, gsl

I am looking into the different routines in the [least squares fitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html#Least_002dSquares-Fitting) documentation, there are multiparameter routines but haven't found any for multivariate response. I am aware that can fit a model for each output but it seems very cumbersome and possibly carries some additional overhead, is there a way of implementing it with GSL?

Comment: In principle you can use multidimensional minimization to do multivariate least square fitting. https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multidimensional-Minimization.html#Multidimensional-Minimization . Not completely straightforward to implement but doable.

Comment: @nopeva: When you talk about models, do you mean linear models or non-linear ones?

Comment: By linear I mean that you seek a matrix *A* and a vector *b* such that *A·x⃗* + *b* for explanatory variable vector *x⃗* best matches the observations vector *y⃗*, that is *A·x⃗* + *b* ≈ *y⃗*.